# How can every thread have its own register?

Tags: cpu, threads

> Threads shares instruction, global and heap regions but has its own
>   individual stack and registers.

How can every thread in a process have its own register, when number of registers is final and constant in a CPU?

Comment: Where exactly did this quote come from?  What is the context of the quote?

Comment: From here https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-process-and-thread.html

Comment: I would not trust that website if I were you.  **The article isn't very technical, it's not clear outside of a single sentence, that the context of threads and processes are entirely within the scope of an operating system.**  Those type of websites are a dime a dozen, they provide "technical information", but there is no substance to anything they author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process thread is an operating system construct. As threads within a process are run and suspended on the CPU their "state" is saved and restored. When a thread is suspended the stack and register states are saved, when the thread is ready to run again its stack and register states are restored to the CPU.

Across threads within a process the global and heap regions are common and information can be shared between threads. The execution state (stack and registers) is *not* shared because if it were then all you would have is a bunch of threads running exactly the same code rather than different code.

The "stack and registers" at this level are the saved states, not the physical CPU registers.

Comment: The stack and register states are saved in RAM?

Comment: @HrvojeT - Depends on if the process is active or not.  The state of an inactive process would be likely be stored within Virtual memory.  Of course an active process that is running, also uses the virtual memory, exact details of what would happen would entirely depend on the OS.